# Что значат webkit и ms?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по всему понял, что -moz это для браузеров mozilla, а -o для опера. Что значат оставшиеся другие?

Answer (score 2):

ms - браузер MicroSoft (IE / edge), а webkit - если вкратце, то Safari (браузер на MacOS) + большинство браузеров на мобилках

Answer (score 1):

`-*-` это "вендорные" приставки для экспериментальных свойств в html движках.

---

`приставка`  *имя движка* (браузеры в которых он используется)

`-о-` *presto* (браузер opera=>blink)

`-ms-` *trident>edgeHTML* (InternetExplorer> EDGE=> blink)

`-moz-` *gecko* (firefox, k-meleon, еще кажется thor и куча прочих)

`-webkit-` *khtml>webkit>blink* (chrome, safari, yandex, Konqueror, vivaldi, opera, edge)

подробнее можно глянуть например тут: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA

---

и кстати. у iphone насколько помню крайне веселые требования к браузерам, типа "делайте чо хотите но браузерный движок должны использовать наш". т.е. на айфонах любой не-сафари это на самом деле лишь скин к сафари. впрочем это не точно.